# VSelect in Vuetify shows empty comment in DOM instead of rendering

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I have added vuetify to my project. The components like v-file-input or v-text-field works just fine. However, v-select doesn't show up. Instead, there is  in the DOM.

http://prntscr.com/p9pmzk

Before adding vuetify I tried Vue-select, but I didn't like it and uninstall that package completely. Vue-select uses the same component name as v-select, not sure could that cause conflicts or not.

```
 `<v-select :items="items" dark outlined></v-select>`
```

```
`    export default {
        name: 'NewIncident',
        data () {
            return {
             items: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Fizz', 'Buzz']
       }
     }
    }`
```

I googled for examples v-select usage and found this codepen.io /DeFrank/pen/BdJyXX

Similarly, it shows up  instead of outputting the desired result

Answer (score 1):

Try adding line

`vuetify: new Vuetify(),`

to your JavaScript export default.

The example mentioned by you will work if you change JavaScript code to:

`new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),`